# Samba default file creation mask calculation

Tags: permissions, samba

Hi I have a question I dont seem find a relevant answer. The situation is that I set samba server and trying to create a file and folder from a windows machine. Everything works as expected but there is the small trouble that samba removes x bit from group and others on file. A simple example code:

```
drwx--x--x.   4 root root  4096 Dec 13 20:01 smb
drwxrwx--x. 2 root amikon 4096 Dec 15 22:17 pokus

[pokus]
path = /smb/pokus
public = no
writable = yes
valid users = @amikon

[root@wserver pokus]# ls -l
drwxr-xr-x. 2 vanek amikon 4096 Dec 21 10:14 dir
-rwxr--r--. 1 vanek amikon    0 Dec 21 10:14 file.txt
```

From many experiments I did I got the understanding that while creating an entry (file or dir) from windows samba performes logical AND from default mask and rights coming from windows machine. This behavior can be more or less influent by using create mask and force create mode (and the other set for dirs) - works as expected with no problem at all.

I found out that the problem of missing 0011 persist regardles using create mask 755 - the x bits are still removed from file. The only option is to use force create mode 755. After that bits stays cuz OR ads them.

I have tested other create mask options and seems to be that 0011 from file is removed everytime. 755, 777, 333 ... so it looks like it could be some protection mechanism removing x from group and others preventing scripts being execute bo nobody but owner????

But my question is about the exact example above. Why there is d755 but -744 as the result. Where exactly the magic of losing 0011 hapened?

Thank much for any hints.

Comment: You may find [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/559114/file-base-permissions-are-666-why-and-is-this-a-configurable-value) to be of some use also.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The magic of losing 0011 happens because it is the default Samba behaviour.

Extract from the doc:

> Create mask : The default value of this parameter removes the group
>   and other write and execute bits from the UNIX modes
>
> Default:
>   create mask = 0744

Here is the link : http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Search for `create mask (S)`

In this doc, Samba team does not explain why they choose to implement this default behaviour, but to me it's easy to think about a security mechanism (as you mentioned).

You can use the `inherit permissions = yes` directive to make a new file inherit its parent folder permission, but this will not affect the x bit.
So, in your case, this will render :

```
-rwxrw-r--. 1 vanek amikon    0 Dec 21 10:14 file.txt
```

Also, as you said, to change this behaviour you will have to explicitly define your own mask.
Now, the main difference between "create" and "force create" is that :

- `create mask` takes permissions away (an AND mask)
- `force create mode` adds them after that (an OR mask)

Also `create mask` is not able to deal with x bit for group and others.

So, you may need to deal with both directive to reach some goals.

---

**Let's try some samples :**

1) If you only want the x bit for group and others you will have to combine :

```
create mask = 0700 #Remove r bit from group and others 
force create mode = 0711 #Add x bit only to group and others
```

**Result :** `-rwx--x--x 1 kris kris   0 Dec 21 14:20 file.txt`

---

2) If you want the r and x bits for group and others, remove `create mask` directive (because default is already 0744) and just add :

```
    ;create mask = 0700 #remove r bit from group and others (commented)
    force create mode = 0711 #Add x bit only to group and others
```

**Result :** `-rwxr-xr-x 1 kris kris   0 Dec 21 14:17 file.txt`

---

And so on...

Hope it helps you a bit to understand Samba behaviours.

Comment: Thank U much for an expalanation ... . One think though. The man page says that " ... removes the group and other WRITE and execute bits from the UNIX modes ...". The x bit was what I asked and it works as expected. But when I set create mask to 777 than I get 766 on a file and for an example when i set create mask to 333 than I get 322 on a file. No force create mode set. It means that the write bit is not really removed regardles man says it supposed to be?

Comment: when you ask for 777 it is normal that you have 766 because `create mask` does not take care of x bit.
Just the same if you ask for 333 you will have 322 because `create mask` does not take care of x bit.
To remove the w bit you have to ask for 0300 or 0344, as 2 is for w

Comment: `It means that the write bit is not really removed regardles man says it supposed to be?` yes it is if you use default behaviour : means without any `create mask` directive. If you declare a `create mask` directive then default behaviour is bypassed for the w bit